# Filter Azure DevOps releases with RestAPIs

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have been working on a requirement with a release API to retain all the production releases.

Code -

```
param (
    [string]$token="",
    [string]$collection="",
    [string]$projectName =""
)
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user, $token)))
$response = Invoke-RestMethod "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$collection/$projectName/_apis/release/definitions?`$expand=Environments&`$top=1000&api-version=6.0" -Method 'GET' -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
foreach ($releaseDefinition in $response.value){
   write-host $releaseDefinition.name
   write-host $releaseDefinition.id
   $releaseDefinitionid =  [convert]::ToInt32($releaseDefinition.id)
   write-host "--------------------------------------------------"
   
   [string] $releases = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$collection/$projectName/_apis/release/releases?definitonid="
   [string] $defid = $releaseDefinitionid
   [string] $geturl = $releases + $defid + "&api-version=6.0"


   
$releaseresult = Invoke-RestMethod $geturl -Method 'GET' -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
#Write-Host $releaseresult.value
#Write-host $releaseresult.keepForever

foreach ($retain in $releaseresult.value)
{

Write-host $retain.id

$temp = $retain.id.ToString()


    $id = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$collection/$projectName/_apis/release/releases/$temp/?api-version=6.0"


$retainrelease = Invoke-RestMethod  $id -Method 'GET' -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
if( $retainrelease.environments.name -eq 'PRD' -and $retainrelease.environments.status -eq 'succeeded')
{
if([string]$retainrelease.keepForever -eq 'False')
{
 
  $keepforever = @{
     keepforever='true'}
    $jsonKeepForever = $keepforever | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
     $uriForBuildUpdate = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$collection/$projectName/_apis/release/releases/$temp/?api-version=6.0"
   $patchreq = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriForBuildUpdate -Method Patch -Body $jsonKeepForever -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}


   Write-Verbose "Result: $patchreq" -Verbose
}

}

 
else
{


}
}
}
```

It retains the releases, but the requirement is to retain only release definitions created in the last 60 days (or a particular date) and retain only releases happened in last 10 days to prod.

I couldn't find any querystring param to filter it by. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried to filtered by created time?

Comment: Yes, somehow that query string param is not resulting the output

Comment: Soory. I cannot understand it. COuld you please describe it in detail?

Answer (score 1):

I found that you can get a list of associated environments like prod/stage/dev (for each definition) by adding the `$expand=environments` to query string.

```
https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/deployments?$expand=environments&api-version=6.0
```

So you'll get the list of all environments and their ids for each definition. The ids can be used as `definitionEnvironmentId` for the other endpoints that seem to have what you're looking for (e.g.: `maxCreatedTime` or `minCreatedTime`) like this one for Releases:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#uri-parameters

Reference:

List of properties that can be expanded - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#releasedefinitionexpands